# Is there a way to replace an object which is referenced in multiple lists with a new instance easily?

Tags: c#, .net, list, reference

I would like to replace an object which is referenced in multiple lists with a new instance of matching interface class.

Here is an example to better understand the problem.

1. There is an interface called `IPosition`
2. There are two classes that implement that interface: `RealPosition` and `AccessiblePosition`
3. In my algorithm I am receiving an array of `IPosition` list, like this: `List<IPosition>[]`, basically multiple lists
4. It is very common that the lists reference the same instance of an object. Here is a visualisation:[image: Multiple List items referencing the same object.]
5. Now I would like to create a `new` instance of the `AccessiblePosition` class and update all references in all lists.

Is there a way to do that easily?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Take every list, find, replace using found index. Easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a container for your data.

```
public interface IContainer<T>
{
    T Data { get; set; }
}
```

And a `List<IContainer<IPosition>>`.

Now you can change `Data` of a container instead of changing item references.

Comment: Could you please make an example? How would I work with this solution and my array of List? Do you mean to have a `List<IContainer<IPosition>>[]`. So basically an array of those lists?

Answer (score 0):

You could just iterate through the lists and compare the items.

```
public interface IPosition
{
    int ID { get; set; }
}

public class RealPosition : IPosition
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public class AccessiblePosition : IPosition
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    var toReplace = new RealPosition { ID = 1 };        
    var list1 = new List<IPosition>
    {
        toReplace,
        new RealPosition { ID = 2 },
        new RealPosition { ID = 3 },
    };
    var list2 = new List<IPosition>
    {
        toReplace,
        new RealPosition { ID = 4 },
        new RealPosition { ID = 5 },
    };
    var listOfLists = new List<List<IPosition>>{ list1, list2 };
    var replacement = new AccessiblePosition{ ID = 42 };

    foreach(var list in listOfLists)
    {
        //must use for here
        for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; ++i)
        {
            if(list[i] == toReplace)
            {                       
                list[i] = replacement;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks @Greg! I thought of this one and it is exactly what I want to avoid. The reason is I have thousands of lists and I need to have a runtime optimised solution.